# Maintaining the same page creating experience in a headless Craft CMS configuration - Next.js

Tags: routing, headless, js

I don't see a clear path to get the full page creating experience in any headless configuration as is available in Craft/Twig. The routing in next.js specifically I think is the main obstacle.

Next.js routing is file-based, so if I want to create a `blog` page, I would create `blog/index.js` as shown:

```
Index routes
The router will automatically route files named index to the root of the directory.

pages/index.js → /
pages/blog/index.js → /blog
```

The file structure below could support my top-level pages, but what about singles, or kitchen sink pages that can be used as a child of any top-level page, or as top-level pages themselves? Where is the ability to create a new entry in a headless Craft setup, and that generate a new page on a next.js frontend?

```
\---pages
    |   index.js
    |   
    +---about
    |   |   index.js
    |   |   
    |   \---[staff]
    |        index.js
    +---blog
    |   |   index.js
    |   |   
    |   \---[post]
    |        index.js
    +---events
    |   |   index.js
    |   |   
    |   \---[event]
    |   |    index.js
    |           
    \---products
        |   index.js
        |   
        \---[product]
             index.js
```

We're all familiar with `section` and `type` in Craft. How would I go about dynamically routing in next.js based on a page's `section` and `type` instead of the filename?

##### Ex:

I have a page with a slug of `widgets`, a section of `pages` and a type of `gadgets`

In Twig, Craft would look in `pageTypes/pages.twig`where I would `include` the page type `{% set type = entry.type %}` `{% include 'pageTypes/' ~ type %}`

Am I approaching this problem the wrong way by trying to solve it the Twig way instead of the Next way? Or is there a solution that mimics/is closer to the way we would do this in a conventional Craft site?

---